# SpringBoot: running a multi module project

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
is a multi-module project with Spring Boot, the project will have 3 modules.
Here the parent module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.tdkcloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>   
        <module>tdk-core</module>
        <module>tdk-batch</module>
        <module>tdk-web</module>
    </modules>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
            <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Email dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Security dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here the module core

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdkcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>


  <groupId>com.tdkcloud.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>    



  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>


        <!--  Hibernate dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.libphonenumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>libphonenumber</artifactId>
            <version>8.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>1.10</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.9.0.pr3</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.9.0.pr3</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>       
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and here the module web:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tdkcloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>tdk-cloud</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

  <groupId>com.tdkcloud.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>tdk-web</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication</start-class>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <!-- tdk-core dependencies -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tdkcloud.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>           
        </dependency> 

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Webjars for JQuery and Bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>


   </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.tdkcloud.TdkCloudApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  

     <!--  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>  -->


</project>
```

from the parent root I generate all the modules using:

```
mvn clean package
```

But the problem is that the `tdk-web-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` does not contain the `tdk-core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` and then it fails on the startup

Here the maven result:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk-cloud calzada$ mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] tdk-cloud
[INFO] tdk-core
[INFO] tdk-batch
[INFO] tdk-web
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdk-cloud 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ tdk-cloud ---
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdk-core 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.194 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-core/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 52 source files to /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ tdk-core ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-core/target/tdk-core-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdk-batch 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-batch/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-batch/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-batch/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-batch/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ tdk-batch ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-batch/target/tdk-batch-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tdk-web 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.6.1:clean (default-clean) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-web/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 339 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 25 source files to /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-web/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.6:jar (default-jar) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/calzada/Development/J2EE/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/tdk-cloud/tdk-web/target/tdk-web-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ tdk-web ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] tdk-cloud ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.105 s]
[INFO] tdk-core ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.634 s]
[INFO] tdk-batch ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.114 s]
[INFO] tdk-web ......................................... SUCCESS [  1.506 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.663 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-30T05:37:04+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/539M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
MacBook-Pro-de-nunito:tdk-cloud calzada$
```

This is the error I got:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field emailService in com.tdkcloud.web.controllers.AppErrorController required a bean of type 'com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailService' in your configuration.
```

I unzipped the jar and there is no class of the core module

adding the proposed code to the module web:

```
<plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

I have the next error:  `Error resolving template "/tdk/login/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Reso`

but the template is there:
[image]

Comment: According to error description, something bad goes wrong with `EmailService`. Do you have `spring.mail.*` settings in your application properties? If not, just provide them.

Comment: can you post the code for EmailService.java?

Comment: Do you have `@Service` annotation on top of `EmailService` class?

Comment: Also, how are you injecting the instance of `EmailService` in impl/ other classes? By autowiring them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, I have tried to implement one of my project structure/layout as maven multi module project.

I followed following spring guide link, hope this will help you and others
[Official Spring multi module project link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/)

Answer (score 3):

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I suggest this for creating a executable Jar.

Answer (score 1):

I think your @ComponentScan annotation is missing, or maybe wrong. (e.g.: @ComponentScan({"com.tdkcloud.web"}) will not find services in com.tdkcloud.backend package). Or maybe @Service annotation is missing from your EmailService.

So to solve this, your code need to look something like this:

App.java (or Webconfig.java)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.tdkcloud"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
   ...
}
```

EmailService.java

```
public interface EmailService {
   ...
}
```

EmailServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `version` in core module. try adding the following core module pom

```
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

so it becomes.

```
<groupId>com.tdkcloud.core</groupId>
<artifactId>tdk-core</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging> 
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: Same result, and I have this warning: Version is duplicate of parent version:

Comment: Make sure that you are doing `mvn clean install`

Comment: I did: mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: can you post the error you are getting while starting the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

> Repackages existing JAR and WAR archives so that they can be executed from the command line using java -jar. With layout=NONE can also be used simply to package a JAR with nested dependencies (and no main class, so not executable).

Got from [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue earlier. I am guessing you are not running the jar in the exploded form. You probably need this plugin to pull the jars inside the bundle and execute the .original jar.

```
               <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

This would bundle all the dependencies you have defined in your pom inside the jar. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot need a bean of type ***com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailService*** and don't find it. you have tow solution:

1- first solution: 
create the bean in your application like this :

```
@Bean
public EmailService EmailService() {
    return new com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailServiceImpl();
}
```

2 - Second solution : 
use **@ComponentScan** like this :

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailService"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

NOTE : you need have spring annotation in your package com.tdkcloud.backend.service.EmailService.